Running strace in Apple Silicon
Environment:

Apple Silicon Mac
Docker desktop for mac
Linux image made by and for x64
Trying to run strace on an executable built for linux x64 through the docker image

I'm getting a whole bunch of this when I run strace:
[ Process PID=46 runs in x32 mode. ]
[ Process PID=46 runs in 64 bit mode. ]
[ Process PID=46 runs in x32 mode. ]
[ Process PID=46 runs in 64 bit mode. ]

I tried doing this on an intel mac and it's giving me way more useful output. Any idea what I'm missing?

Hi, did you find a solution ?

@Furlings Not with docker or even parallels running Linux since they're all virtualizations. Emulation through QEMU works. I'm using UMT to get my QEMU set up.
